# WPF DataGrid Move to last selected row without highlight recent clicked row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have DataGrid and added event as below, performing some calculation for validation, if validation is success then nothing to do. But if validation get failed then highlighted row should be still last selected row, not newly clicked row:-

```
        public void dataGridTable_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (dataGrid.SelectedIndex == lastSelectedIndex)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

    /*



   Validate method will return true if row validation is fine else false.

        */
    if(!validate())
    {
    // Revert to last selected index.
        dataGrid.SelectedIndex = lastSelectedIndex;
    }
     }
```

`dataGrid.SelectedIndex = lastSelectedIndex;` this code will make selected index as a last selected index (at c# code i check it in debug mode) but in WPF DataGrid still highlight newly clicked row.

Please let me know if i am  not clear enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the selected cells using the [DataGrid.SelectedCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Just do

```
this.SelectedCells.Clear();
```

to clear the current selection.

Or if you want to select cells in the current row of the SelectedIndex you can do

```
this.SelectAllCells();
DataGridCellInfo[] cells = this.SelectedCells.Where(x => this.Items.IndexOf(x.Item) == this.SelectedIndex).ToArray();
this.SelectedCells.Clear();
foreach (DataGridCellInfo cell in cells)
{
     this.SelectedCells.Add(cell);
}
```

Where `this` is the instance of the DataGrid.